# SQLite select field if text inside contains a specific text

Tags: sql, database, string, sqlite

I want to select field if the text inside contains a specific word in addition to the entire text, for example:

field value = `Hello, World!`

I want to select this field according to the text `Hel`

Thanks!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE field LIKE "Hel%"
```

You could also do LIKE "%Hel%" which would select a field containing the string "Hel" anywhere within it as opposed to "Hel%" which requires that the string starts with "Hel"

Comment: There is also a [full text search](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) extension to SQLite that one can install.

Comment: Is there any way I can delete any text that con taint "Hel" for example automatically ?

Comment: Are you wanting to delete the row, the word or just 'hel'?  AND is it CASE Sensitive?

Comment: use the [replace](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) function as found in docs.  Replace(Col,'hel','')  or more complete `update table set field = Replace(field,'hel','')`